# Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process even calling FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mobile

Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process EVEN calling FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

The error happens when I try to use Firestore dependence

> app/build.gradle

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

}

android {
    compileSdk 34
    namespace 'com.x.y'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.allapps.qrcode"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 22
        versionName "1.1.10"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation project(path: ':AllAds')
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.4.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:20.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.3.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf-ktx:20.3.1'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx:18.3.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:21.3.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

> build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.20"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> The error log is below.

[image: Error]

Comment: are you sure google play services file is placed in correct place?

Comment: Yeah, I am sure!

Answer (score 0):

Please try writing
maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
rather than maven
{ url "https://jitpack.io" }

Comment: I tried, but still doesn`t work.